# Can't call FB.ui in dev (localhost) environment

Tags: facebook, localhost, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-ui

I used to be able to, but for some reason all my Facebook Javascript API calls using FB.ui() no longer work in my development environment where my url is localhost:8080.  In production it works fine though.  I have a dev environment Facebook application, but I did just change URLs around in it.  I assume that's where the problem is.  How do I have a Facebook application that allows FB.ui() calls from dev and production environments?  This is the error I get when calling FB.UI() in dev:

```
An error occurred with AppleTree dev. Please try again later.

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I always add a entry in my hosts file for something like:

```
127.0.0.1  dev.mydomain.com
```

And then set my app domain in the app settings to mydomain.com (to allow subdomains).  Then access your site in your browser at http://dev.mydomain.com:8080 and FB.ui should allow the call.

Comment: This is a good solution, but my issue was actually because a setting was changed in Facebook that I didn't realize would affect my dev facebook app.

Comment: what was the setting if you dont mind sharing with us. I am sure community might benefit from it